# Handlebar if condition in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, handlebars.js

Am using handlebar js to make a selectbox.

```
<select id="order_status_selection">
{{#each orders_status}} 
  <option value="{{id}}" {{#ifCond id status}} selected {{/ifCond}}> {{title}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>
```

in js file am using a handlebar register

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if(v1 === v2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

i need to add selected tag when my id == status

when i execute this code outside the selectbox (in a div) the selected tag is printing but it doesn't print inside  `<option></option>`

Am new to handlebar any advice will be helpful

Comment: Can you confirm that `id` and `status` are of the same type?

Comment: The helper is correct, have in mind that you have `===`, instead of `==` so `v1` and `v2` should have the same time as @76484 said. Drop some console logs inside the helper and check if you're getting the correct values.